# Error when I'm trying to run the log in activity on real device (works perfect on emulator)

Tags: php, android, authentication, android-activity, emulation

I develop an android app and I have problem when I run the app on real device. On emulator everything work properly.
When the activity starts I fill username and password and I press log in button. Nothing happens and after 2-3 mins I have the errors bellow.

This is the LogInActivity.java

```
package com.example.movenialapplication;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LogInActivity extends Activity{

IpString ipStr = new IpString();
static String ip = IpString.ipAdress;
private static String url_logIn = "http://"+ip+"/android_nydor/login3.php";
Button btnForLogIn;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
String username,password;
EditText usernameTxt;
EditText passwordTxt;

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_USERS = "users";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.log_in);
    btnForLogIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LogInButton);
    btnForLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            usernameTxt =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
            passwordTxt =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            username = usernameTxt.getText().toString();
            password = passwordTxt.getText().toString();
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                // Note that product details url will use GET request

                //StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                //StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_logIn, "GET", params);
                //Log.i("jsonOb", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // Starting new intent
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            AllFromMovenialActivity.class);
                    // sending pid to next activity
                    //in.putExtra(TAG_ID, movenialID);

                    // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                    startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                }
                else{
                    usernameTxt.setText("") ;
                    passwordTxt.setText("") ;
                    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.WrongPassword);
                    t.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

and here is the php code:

```
<?php
//opening connection link
$link_fetch_data = mysql_connect('localhost:3306', 'root', 'pass');

$username=$_GET['username'];
$password=$_GET['password'];

if (!$link_fetch_data) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
//selecting db from server
mysql_select_db("sccm_nydor", $link_fetch_data);

$q=mysql_query("SELECT idusers FROM users WHERE username='".$_GET['username']."' AND password = SHA1(CONCAT('".$_GET['username']."','".$_GET['password']."')) AND active=1");

if (!empty($q)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($q) > 0) {

            $q = mysql_fetch_array($q);

            $movenial_users = array();

            $movenial_users["idusers"]=$q["idusers"];

            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["movenial_users"] = array();

            array_push($response["movenial_users"], $movenial_users);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } 
        else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No contents found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }    
} 
else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}

mysql_close($link_fetch_data);          
?>
```

And this is the Log:

```
05-15 13:56:18.075: E/Buffer Error(7588): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 13:56:18.075: E/JSON Parser(7588): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
05-15 13:56:18.085: E/AndroidRuntime(7588): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 13:56:18.085: E/AndroidRuntime(7588): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 13:56:18.085: E/AndroidRuntime(7588):     at com.example.movenialapplication.LogInActivity$1.onClick(LogInActivity.java:65)
05-15 13:56:18.085: E/AndroidRuntime(7588):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3538)
05-15 13:56:18.085: E/AndroidRuntime(7588):     at  android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14330)
05-15 13:56:18.085: E/AndroidRuntime(7588):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
05-15 13:56:18.085: E/AndroidRuntime(7588):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-15 13:56:18.085: E/AndroidRuntime(7588):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
05-15 13:56:18.085: E/AndroidRuntime(7588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
05-15 13:56:18.085: E/AndroidRuntime(7588):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 13:56:18.085: E/AndroidRuntime(7588):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-15 13:56:18.085: E/AndroidRuntime(7588):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-15 13:56:18.085: E/AndroidRuntime(7588):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-15 13:56:18.085: E/AndroidRuntime(7588):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your real device is connected to the same network as the PC, if your PHP script is located on your PC, the IP address for your Real Device must be the same with the PC.

Hope this helps, good luck ^^

Comment: Thanks for the reply.My device is connected to the same network.And the php script is located on my pc and i run it with xampp. Can u help me more now?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I suspect your problem is here:

```
IpString ipStr = new IpString();
static String ip = IpString.ipAdress;
```

What is the value of `ip`? I'm not familiar with  the class `IpString`, but I suspect on the emulator it is returning `10.0.2.2` or the actual IP address of the host, which is the device I imagine your server is running on. However, on a real device, the IP address will most certainly not be the address of your server, thus the `jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_logIn, "GET", params)` call will fail. Specifically, I suspect `JSONObject json` is null, giving you the null pointer exception you report in your LogCat.

Comment: IpString is class and from there i change the ip address! there is nothing wrong there! i just parse the ip dynamically.

Comment: @mantsap: Have you checked the IP address reported? Your reply suggests to me that you haven't checked the value on the physical device. BTW, can you access your server from the browser on the physical device?

Comment: I checked it and i cant access my server from the phone's browser. (192.168.1.5/....)

Comment: i found what was wrong! firewall didnt allow me to connect to xampp from my android device!Thanks again